# UIGestureRecognizer delete specific UIImageView on which LongPress is applied

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm working on an app in which you add different images from gallery to the view you can drag them around and if you press long on an image it should delete it. The new imported image is placed in a `CGRect` and then the functionality of drag and longpress is applied to it.

My question is from my delete code, deletion is working but it only delete the last inserted image.

```
self.myImageView = [[Draggable alloc]initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
[self.myImageView setImage:self.myImage];
[self.myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.myImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.myImageView setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:YES];

[self.customCam addSubview:self.myImageView];
```

This code is allocating draggable class to a UIImageView which is used to drag the image around the screen. Below is the long press gesture code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(activateDeletionMode:)];
    longPress.delegate = self;
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    [self.myImageView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

and `activateDeletionMode` code is below

```
- (void)activateDeletionMode:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
            [self.myImageView removeFromSuperview];
            NSLog(@"This Runs");
        }
}
```

With only one image inserted it works fine. But if I insert 2 images at the same time it delete the latest inserted image and didn't perform the `removeFromSuperview`on second image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a new longpress gesture for every imageView.

Comment: Every time a new image view is added this line `[self.myImageView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];` adds a new longpress gesture to it. But if a new is added this control is transferred to the new one. So how can I do that it generates new longpress to every new my imageview?

Comment: If you create a few imageViews, you should create a NSArray to contain the imageViews. So code is `for imageView in imagesViews{ UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(activateDeletionMode:)]; [imageView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];}`